# PostgreSQL - How to get aggregation of data with foreign keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'll outline my goal:

I have users, which are the players in a sports league.

I have a table with sports seasons called "seasons".

I have a table with games, which hold various properties such as if the game is completed, etc. and also hold a season_id.

I have a table of "Stat Lines", which hold a foreign key to the related game. To keep it simple, let's say that the stat_lines table just holds goals, assists, game_id, season_id, and user_id.

So, lets say Sidney Crosby was a user with id=1 and had a stat line with goals=2, assists=3, game_id=4, season_id=1, and user_id=1.

What I want in the end is season-by-season totals for each player:

Player
Season
Goals
Assists
Points

1 (Crosby) - Season 1 - 10 - 12 - 22

1 (Crosby) - Season 2 - 10 - 10 - 20

2 (Bergeron) - Season 1 - 0 - 4 - 4

I'm not sure how to do this.

It feels like I would need to do two GROUP BY calls, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't that just

```
SELECT user_id, season_id, sum(goals), sum(assists), sum(goals) + sum(assists)
FROM stat_lines
GROUP BY user_id, season_id
ORDER BY user_id, season_id;
```

?

Comment: Jeeze. Thank you. I am quite obviously new to SQL. I am used to Ruby on Rails, where it abstracts the SQL, but I am looking to improve efficiency via database views. Thank you again, I appreciate it. I will make sure to mark your answer correct when the timer allows.